# Does changing the SSH comment of a public key affect the key itself?

Tags: ssh

Let's say my id_rsa.pub looks like:

```
ssh-rsa SOMERSAVALUE SOMECOMMENT
```

If I change SOMECOMMENT to something else, will it still be valid for authorization with the private key?

What's the proper way to change it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the comment does not affect the public key. You are welcome to change it however you like. Public key authentication will still work.